# Passing instance method as callback in class initializer

Tags: swift

Consider the following code:

```
class Bar {
    let callback: () -> ()

    init(callback: @escaping () -> ()) {
        self.callback = callback
    }

    func event() {
        self.callback()
    }
}

class Foo {
    let bar: Bar

    init() {
        self.bar = Bar(callback: self.handler)
    }

    func handler() {
        print("Handled")
    }
}
```

The basic idea is that we want each `Foo` to have a `Bar`, which, when `event()` is called on a `Foo`'s `bar`, will call `Foo`'s handler method. However, the setup above warns on `Foo`'s init since we're using `self` before all instance properties have been initialized.

I understand *why* this is an error: the compiler cannot guarantee that the method passed to `Bar`'s initializer won't be called somehow before `Foo`'s initializer finishes (e.g. `Bar` may call the `callback` param right in it's initializer, or another thread may call `event()` just after `Bar`'s initializer returns but just before the result is assigned to `Foo`'s `bar`).

My question is, is there is a way to implement this pattern that I'm missing? One workaround is to make `bar` an IUO `var` and assign it to `nil` just before calling `Bar`'s `init`--as long as *we* know the callback won't be called at an improper time (or as long as we don't use `bar` in `handler`) there shouldn't be an issue. However, this feels pretty hacky to me and I'd love to hear alternatives if they exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another option:

```
class Foo {
    let bar: Bar

    init() {
        self.bar = Bar(callback: self.handler)
    }

    let handler: () -> Void = {
        print("handled")
    }
}
```

Maybe it doesn't feel quite as hacky, but if `handler` deals with `self` at all, this won't work. You can't do it with a Delegate either.

Yea, AFAIK, the only way to do this is to make `bar` an implicitly unwrapped `var`

```
class Foo {
    var bar: Bar!

    init() {
        bar = Bar(callback: handler)
    }

    func handler() {
        print("Handled")
    }
}
```

Comment: That’s actually not a bad solution, and looks a little cleaner. Another solution is to have a `listenForEvents(callback:)` method on `Bar` and have the callback be optional (or IUO).